# plsql query to update line numbers based on the header no's

Tags: sql, oracle

can anybody help me with this requirement.

i have a sample table like below, with 3 header records:

```
PO_HEADER ||    ITEM   || LINE_NUM

   1              X 
   1              Y 
   2              Z 
   2              A 
   3              B
```

i need to update LINE_NUM  to this particular header records like table below.

```
PO_HEADER ||    ITEM   || LINE_NUM

   1              X          1      
   1              Y          2
   2              Z          1
   2              A          2
   3              B          1
   4              C          1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Questions like "how to do this" without showing any effort are not usually welcome here. Besides, what is the logic behind your need? For example, for po_header=1 you seem to order by ITEM, but not for po_header=2

Comment: You also haven't explained the logic - looks like you want the rank (hint) within the header ordered by item alphabetically, but we shouldn't need to guess. Do you really need to store this when it can be calculated on the fly, maybe in a view? What happens to existing line numbers if a row is removed or inserted? And why do you want to do this in PL/SQL?

Comment: What is a plsql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the row_number function to accomplish this:

```
create table tx (po_header number(1), item varchar2(1), line_num number(1));

insert into tx values (1,'X', null);
insert into tx values (1,'Y', null);
insert into tx values (2,'Z', null);
insert into tx values (2,'A', null);
insert into tx values (3,'B', null);
insert into tx values (4,'C', null);

update tx a
set a.line_num = (select y.line_num
                  from (select x.po_header, x.item, row_number () over (partition by x.po_header order by x.item) line_num
                        from tx x) y
                  where y.po_header = a.po_header
                    and y.item = a.item);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you . it worked to update. but can u plase help me with this requirement for the same question like , after updating the line_num's for every po_header. after updating we have few more null values in line_num. we need to update the sequnce next number for particular header

Comment: po_header Item line_num
1 X 1
1 Y 2
1 z null
1 p null
2 c null
2 A 1
2 d null
2 Z 2
3 e null
3 f null
3 B 1
4 g null
4 h null
4 C 1

Comment: just run the same update again, but now for the null values only and adjust your order by in the row_number function so the null values come last

Comment: please accept this as an answer then if it worked for you

Comment: @arifmd - Kaushik Nayak already pointed you to ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in the help center, in a comment under your question.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use of `row_number()` function :

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by po_header order by ?) as LineNum
from table t;
```

`?` indicates your ordering column that specify your table data ordering.